# How do I get an asp.net 3.5 textbox input into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, windows

Looking at many forums this seems to be the solution, however, it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
 function update() {

     alert("hello world");

     var test = document.getElementById("<%=InCL.ClientID%>").value;    

     alert(test);

 }
```

and the asp/html is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InCL" runat="server" Text="" value="" onchange="update()"></asp:TextBox>
```

seems I am missing something simple? I also tried using single quotes with <%=InCL.ClientID%>

The alert "hello world" pops-up on change, but not for test...

Using asp.net 3.5, FF, master pages, etc...

Thanks.

**EDIT**
So I changed it to use this.value and that works, but still no solution in to how to get it by id?

works:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InCL" runat="server" Text="" value="1" onchange="update(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>
```

with:

```
function update(x) {

     alert(x);


 }
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript located? In the aspx page?

Comment: Can you "view source" from your browser, and confirm that the `id` in `document.getElementById()` matches the `id` of the text box?

Comment: @Russ Cam: it is in a external .js - added in the master page - <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  and does work as the hello world pops-up.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: in the html the id is a weird dynamic id, what do I match it too? where do I see what the id in document.getElementById()  turns into?

Comment: @Greg: Yes, it's supposed to be dynamic. For example: `document.getElementById('ctrl_00incl')` should match with an `<input type="text" id="ctrl_00incl" />` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: but I  DONT put that dynamic value into the javascript, right?

Comment: @Greg: No, the `<%=InCL.ClientID%>` is supposed to resolve into that dynamic id, but it's not happening because of the reasons @Russ pointed out below.

Comment: What about adding an attribute to the label name="myVal" and use getElementByName() ? Any issue with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that the JavaScript is in an external js file that does not go through the processing pipeline and is served statically from disk. The Server side tag  <%=InCL.ClientID%> needs to go through the processing pipeline to render out the id string of the server control.

The simplest way to resolve this is to put the script element in the page. Other ways are to define only the JavaScript that has server tags in the page and assign to a global variable. Then define your external script after the global variable declaration and assignment - you can then use this variable in the external script file.

Comment: Ok that does makes sense, I'll take your word for it...thanks. However, I can't believe there is not a way to bridge that pipeline to external files...crazy.

Comment: @RPM1984: I'll still give you +1 if you answer...haha no really.

Comment: Hehe, well that was my point, i only saw "new answer posted" just before i was about to post the answer. I thought, what the heck, i may as well post my answer. Anyway your problem is solved, that's the main thing.

Comment: Well, there are ways of getting JavaScript with server tags to run through pipeline, but it requires some trickery in that the script goes in a user control. This will still end up sending the script with the page though as the script needs page context to get the control id

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your JavaScript file is external, so it has no visibility or sense of the wirings between the current HTML page and the server.

This is probably your best bet

Declare a literal control on the page:

```
<asp:Literal id="variables" runat="server" />
```

Set it to the client id:

```
variables.Text = string.Format("var myclientid='{0}';", Incl.ClientID);
```

Then you can access it from your external JS file:

```
document.getElementById(myclientid);
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply pass "this" rather than "this.value"? (No quotes in the actual code, obviously.) If you pass the actual field object, you can derive the id, the value, any parents, grandparents or siblings hanging around the old DOM neighborhood -- and you get to have a reusable chunk of code that can be dropped in anywhere without having to hardcode an id value. (Even if the code is only ever used on this one form, what happens when you decide to overhaul the form?)